# get the name of most recent file in linux - PYTHON

Tags: python

I want to get the name of the most recent file from a particular directory in python?

I used this

```
import os
import glob

def get_latest_file(path, *paths):
    """Returns the name of the latest (most recent) file
    of the joined path(s)"""
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, *paths)
    print fullpath
    list_of_files = glob.glob(fullpath)  
    if not list_of_files:               
        return None                     
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    _, filename = os.path.split(latest_file)
    return filename


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print get_latest_file('ocr', 'uploads', '*.png')
```

[Source](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120494/finding-the-latest-file-in-a-folder)

But I want the code to return name of the most recent file without specifying extension of file. 
So let's say if there are jpg, jpeg, png, gif

I want the snippet to cover them all.

Any inputs?

Comment: with glob.glob you can also replace the file ending suffix. did you try out: print get_latest_file('ocr', 'uploads', '*')

Comment: @hasan That is the answer. Do you want to write it down more clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with your last line you just retrieve the files with .png extension

```
get_latest_file('ocr', 'uploads', '*.png')
```

if you want to retrieve all files not depending on the extension, you just need to remove your extension specification in code to glob.glob('*'). This will retrieve all files in your directory. if you still need any extension but it doesnt matter which you also could retrieve them with glob.glob(*.*) i think.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the extension a simple os.walk iteration will do. You can extend this to filter extensions if you need.

```
import os

all_files = {}
root = 'C:\workspace\werkzeug-master'
for r, d, files in os.walk(root):
    for f in files:
        fp = os.path.join(root, r, f)
        all_files[os.path.getmtime(fp)] = fp
keys = all_files.keys()
keys.sort(reverse = True)
print all_files[keys[0]]
```